# Perl YAML to JSON

Tags: json, perl, yaml

What I am trying to do should be VERY straightforward and simple.

```
use JSON;
use YAML;
use Data::Dumper;

my $yaml_hash = YAML::LoadFile("data_file.yaml");
print ref($yaml_hash) # prints HASH as expected
print Dumper($yaml_hash) # correctly prints the hash
my $json_text = encode_json($yaml_hash);
```

The encode_json errors out saying:

```
cannot encode reference to scalar 'SCALAR(0x100ab630)' unless the scalar is 0 or 1
```

I am not able to understand why encode_json thinks that $yaml_hash is a reference to a scalar when in fact it is a reference to a HASH

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that JSON is a *subset* of YAML, and if the data uses only the features supported by JSON then no translation is necessary. On the other hand, if the data does use some features special to YAML, then translation isn't possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`YAML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/YAML/lib/YAML.pod) enables you to load objects and scalar references.  [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) does not by default

I suspect that your data file most likely contains an inside-out object, and JSON doesn't know how to work with the scalar reference.

The following demonstrates loading a YAML hash containing a scalar reference in one of the values and then failing to encode it using JSON:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use YAML;
use JSON;

# Load a YAML hash containing a scalar ref as a value.
my ($hashref) = Load(<<'END_YAML');
---
bar: !!perl/ref
  =: 17
foo: 1
END_YAML

use Data::Dump;
dd $hashref;

my $json_text = encode_json($hashref);
```

Output:

```
{ bar => \17, foo => 1 }
cannot encode reference to scalar at script.pl line 18.
```

Comment: Crystal clear answer! Thanks a lot. My YAML did have such a scalar reference.

Answer (score 5):

It is not $yaml_hash that it is complaining about, it is some reference in one of the hash values (or deeper).  Scalar references can be represented in YAML but not in JSON.

Comment: Wish I could +1 your answer. I don't have enough reputation. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

Here are one liners that can be used to pipe `YAML` in and produce `JSON` on `STDOUT`

```
perl -0777 -MYAML -MJSON -e 'print(JSON->new()->utf8()->pretty()->encode(Load(<STDIN>)))'
```

or even shorter if you don't care for formatting

```
perl -0777 -MYAML -MJSON -e 'print encode_json(Load(<STDIN>))'
```

For large volumes and faster parsing I'd also recommend using `YAML::XS` and `JSON::XS` counterparts